# Were the majority of people killed in the last two Chechen Wars ethnic Russians?

Tags: russia

This New York Times article relays the following numbers with the benefit of doubt ([NYT: Chechen official puts death toll for 2 wars at up to 160,000 [paywalled]](https://www.nytimes.com/2005/08/16/world/europe/chechen-official-puts-death-toll-for-2-wars-at-up-to-160000.html)):
160 000 killed, 100 000 of them ethnic Russians, among them 90 000 civilians. Contrasted by only 40 000 ethnic Chechens killed.

This high number of Russian casualties is explained by Russia's indiscriminate use of violence in Grosny in the first Chechen war, while the majority of inhabitants were still ethnic Russians.

Are these numbers considered credible, or is at least a very high proportion of ethnic Russian civilian deaths attested?

Comment: You can start by looking at the Wikipedia articles [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Chechen_War#Casualties) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Chechen_War#Civilian_losses). As you will see, the estimates vary.

Comment: For further details, see also [casualties of the second Chechen war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casualties_of_the_Second_Chechen_War), and [second Chechen war crimes and terrorism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Chechen_War_crimes_and_terrorism), linked in the two articles posted above.

Comment: Lot of ethnic Russians were killed by Chechen "authorities" (i.e. gangs) even before first Chechen war started. This was actually main motivation that forced weak Yeltsin government to intervene, although they were reluctant do so.